# Locust class-picker mode auto reset statistic when ramping up users

Tags: python, load-testing, locust, webui

currently I have started working with Locust. I follow the [class-picker docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#running-locust-with-user-class-ui-picker) and practice with a simple test, but quickly realized that every time I increase the number of users during the test, Locust will **reset the statistics table**. Besides, Locust behevior of ramping up users is quite strange: instead of increasing from 2 users to 5 users, it **set the number of users to 0 first and then increase to 5**. Is that an obvious thing when running Locust in class-picker mode?

Here is *test.py*

```
from locust import HttpUser, constant, task


class MyReqRes1(HttpUser):

    wait_time = constant(1)
    host = "http://example.com"

    @task
    def get_users(self):
        res = self.client.get("/hello")
        print(res.status_code)

class MyReqRes2(HttpUser):

    wait_time = constant(1)
    host = "http://example.com"

    @task
    def get_users(self):
        res = self.client.get("/world")
        print(res.status_code)
```

And here is my command to run:

```
locust -f test.py --class-picker
```

I am trying to keep Locust ramping up users normally (the way it do without --class-picker arguments) and keep the statistic table as well.

Answer (score 1):

The user class UI picker is designed to let you choose a user class to use for the test run. This means that user class will be used for the whole duration of the test. If you want to choose a different user class, you need to start a new test which results in the behavior you described: Locust stops all currently running users, resets the stats, switches user classes, starts the new test by spawning new users at your defined spawn rate to reach the number of desired users.

In other words, it's designed to let you have multiple different test scenarios defined in the same file and let you choose the one you want at run time.

The user class UI picker does *not* allow you to choose one user class, start a test and get X number of users, choose another class, add Y users, choose another class, add Z users, end up with X+Y+Z running users, which sounds like what you're trying to do. There is not currently a way to accomplish that.

Of course, you're welcome to put together a pull request with that kind of behavior and it can be reviewed and perhaps included in a future version.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I didn't expect it to be that fast. I totally understand what you are saying, but in my case I only modified the number of users in ONE class, which means at first I had 2 users of class X, then I increase to 5 users of class X. Now it is stranger right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. I'd recommend testing your scenario without using the class picker and see if you get the same behavior. But it's possible that's expected behavior? I'd have to look at the code to know. You can always file a bug or better yet submit a PR with a fix for it, if it actually is broken.

Comment: Yeah I have tested again without the class picker and Locust run as expected. Besides I borrow a Macbook from my co-worker and Locust class-picker mode runs totally fine, that is the reason I believe there is something wrong with my machine. Can you please test this issue on your computer too?